# Load Map with bubbles on page load in android

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, osmdroid, itemizedoverlay

In my application there is a map and the map has many pins. When the user taps on a pin, name of the touched pin appears in a balloon. What I want is to display all balloons on page loads, not when the user touches a pin. I have written the ItemizedOverlayWithBubble class and it overrides a method called onSingleTapUpHelper:

```
@Override protected boolean onSingleTapUpHelper(final int index, final Item item, final MapView mapView) {
        showBubbleOnItem(index, mapView, true);
        return true;
    }
```

Inside that there is another method call showBubbleOnItem(index, mapView, true);

```
public void showBubbleOnItem(final int index, final MapView mapView, boolean panIntoView) {
        ExtendedOverlayItem eItem = (ExtendedOverlayItem)(getItem(index)); 
        mItemWithBubble = eItem;
        if (eItem != null){
            eItem.showBubble(mBubble, mapView, panIntoView);
            //setFocus((Item)eItem);
        }
    }
```

I played around with it for a while to see if I could get it working on page load but got no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly your points are overlaps with each other. Especially if you create `GeoPoint`s from integers with small difference like 11,1 and 12,2 and 13,3 this will couse overlaped overlay items

Have a look at here
[package org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/org/osmdroid/util/GeoPoint.java?r=667)
when you use

`GeoPoint(final int aLatitudeE6, final int aLongitudeE6)`

Your value will not be multiplyed with 1E6(which is 1.000.000)
So there is no place difference between this two points on `MapView`

`GeoPoints(11,1)` and  `GeoPoints(12,2)`